Getting EndorseError: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:grpcs://localhost:9051 while using fabric-gateway
I am trying to create a gateway using @hyperledger/fabric-gateway module in Nodejs.
I am able to enroll the admin and the user but after creating the gateway the NetworkImpl and ContractImpl both are blank.
and when trying to run the submitTransaction method it gives out this error:
NetworkImpl {}
ContractImpl {}

/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:36

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.#client.makeUnaryRequest(exports.endorseMethod, serialize, deserializeEndorseResponse, request, buildOptions(this.#defaultOptions.endorseOptions, options), newUnaryCallback(resolve, reject, (err) => new endorseerror_1.EndorseError(Object.assign(err, { transactionId: request.getTransactionId() })))));
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^

EndorseError: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:grpcs://localhost:9051
    at /home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:36:253
    at Object.callback (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:101:20)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 14,

  details: [],

  cause: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:grpcs://localhost:9051
      at callErrorFromStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
      at /home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:99:78
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
  for call at
      at Client.makeUnaryRequest (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:32)
      at /home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:36:62
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at GatewayClientImpl.endorse (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:36:16)
      at ProposalImpl.endorse (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/proposal.js:43:52)
      at async ContractImpl.submitAsync (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/contract.js:48:29)
      at async ContractImpl.submit (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/contract.js:40:27)
      at async getContractObject (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:126:18)
      at async main (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:173:32) {
    code: 14,
    details: 'Name resolution failed for target dns:grpcs://localhost:9051',
    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
  },
  transactionId: '2778594f7660710c77d4a08c5f9ad943da3cf0e4c10db2523840dce29b0f0f90'
}



This the function using the gateway:
const getContractObject = async (wallet, ccp, userName, org, contractName) => {
    let identity = await wallet.get(userName);
    client = await getClient(ccp, userName, org);
    const gateway = connect({
        client,
        identity: await getIdentity(identity),
        signer: getSigner(identity)
    });

    const network = await gateway.getNetwork(process.env.CHANNEL);
    console.log(network)
    let contract = await network.getContract(contractName);
    console.log(contract)
    // console.log(contract.getContractName())
    let result = await contract.submitTransaction('CreateEvidence', "xyxyx", userName, "100", "Hacking", "xss.png", "png", "zzzzz");
    console.log(result)
    // return result
}

helper functions:

const getClient = async (ccp, userName, org) => {

    console.log(ccp.peers[`${userName}.${org}.evidence-vault.com`].url)
    const tlsCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(Buffer.from(ccp.peers[`${userName}.${org}.evidence-vault.com`].tlsCACerts.pem));

    return new grpc.Client(ccp.peers[`${userName}.${org}.evidence-vault.com`].url, tlsCredentials, {
        'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': ccp.peers[`${userName}.${org}.evidence-vault.com`].grpcOptions.ssl_target_name_override,
    });
};


const getSigner = (identity) => {
    const privateKeyPem = identity.credentials.privateKey;
    const privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey(privateKeyPem);
    return signers.newPrivateKeySigner(privateKey);
};

const getIdentity = async (identity) => {
    return { mspId: identity.mspId, credentials: identity.credentials.certificate };
};

The connection profile which i am using

{
    "name": "EvidenceVault-Forensic",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Forensic",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Police": {
            "mspid": "ForensicMSP",
            "peers": [
                "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "/home/kshitij/Desktop/EvidenceVault/artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/forensic.evidence-vault.com/peers/FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.forensic.evidence-vault.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        },
        "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "/home/kshitij/Desktop/EvidenceVault/artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/forensic.evidence-vault.com/peers/FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.forensic.evidence-vault.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8054",
            "caName": "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "/home/kshitij/Desktop/EvidenceVault/artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/forensic.evidence-vault.com/ca/ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}

I think the name resolution error is because there is nothing present in the NetworkImpl and ContractImpl, Why is it happening?

The documentation for the address format used when creating a gRPC Client is here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md
Rather than grpcs://localhost:9051 that you extracted from your common connection profile, you should be using either dns:///localhost:9051 or simply localhost:9051, since the default is to use DNS name resolution when no scheme is specified.

Hi, I changed the url and it connected but threw a new eror: EndorseError: 10 ABORTED: failed to endorse transaction details: [     {       address: 'FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com:9051',       message: 'error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mainchannel] creator org unknown, creator is malformed',       mspId: 'ForensicMSP'     }, 
